# Программирование потоков в Linux

Tags: c, c++, linux

Как в Linux измерить время работы потока и процесса ?

Как назначить приоритет потоку и процессу ?

Как в Linux подождать, пока не выполнятся все потоки (что-то типо наподобее функции WaitForMultipleObjects() в WinApi) ?

Comment: Делать алгоритм, рассчитывая на игру с приоритетами не самая лучшая идея.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Приоритеты - [pthread_setschedparam](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man3/pthread_setschedparam.3.html).

Аналог `WaitForMultipleObjects` - [pthread_join](http://www.opennet.ru/man.shtml?topic=pthread_join&category=3&russian=5).

Comment: насколько я понял, pthread_join работает только с одним потоком. или я неправ ? А если потоки генерируются динамически ? Тоесть есть массив потоков.

Comment: да, с одним. Если нужно ждать несколько потоков, то можно просто ждать их по очереди. никуда не убегут.

Comment: можно, если известно сколько их.

Comment: А можно сделать семафор. Когда треды запускаются - они увеличивают на единицу. Когда завершаются - уменьшают. Всех то делов.

Comment: А время работы потока возможно как-то измерить? Существуют ли специальные функции для этого дела ?

Comment: @nullptr, Вы меряете свои потоки? Если так, то возьмите время в начале функции, вызываемой в pthread_create и в ее конце. Разность либо верните (возьмете join-ом) или положите куда удобно.

Кстати, Вам видимо известно, что join можно вызывать (в отличии от fork) не только в том потоке, который сделал create? Это может облегчить Вашу задачу. 

Создаете поток, который подбирает всех завершившихся, выбирая их thread_t из очереди (примитивно из pipe) в которую они же сами его и кладут перед return.